# Remove string from array if specific characters present in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm working on some Swift code to run through an array of strings (teams) and if special characters from another array (charsToRemove) are present, remove the item from the teams array. Alternatively, I'd also be OK with adding items that do NOT contain a special character to an array as well. Here is some sample data:

```
teams = ["lime", "teal/gold", "red-2", "orange", "orange(6)", "blue-7" ... ]
charsToRemove = [ "(", ")", "-", " ", "/" ... ]
```

The final result should look like:

```
teams = ["lime", "orange"]
```

I've tried a few iterations of loops but looking for what might be the best route. The teams array and special characters is a bit longer but didn't want to paste too much on here.

Comment: It's useful to understand the mindset behind the answers. Your questions boils down into two parts: "Remove string from array if" -> That's a `filter(_:)` operation, `if specific characters present in swift` -> so we need to determine what the predicate is for `filter(_:)`. From there, people gravitated to either using `Array.contains(_:)` or `CharacterSet(_:)`. It's useful to break down problems into sub-problems like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use String method `rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet)` to check if it finds a range of a character set and use it to filter your array:

```
let teams = ["lime", "teal/gold", "red-2", "orange", "orange(6)", "blue-7"]
let charsToRemove = [ "(", ")", "-", " ", "/" ]
let cs = CharacterSet(charactersIn: charsToRemove.joined())
let filtered = teams.filter({ $0.rangeOfCharacter(from: cs) == nil })
print(filtered)   // ["lime", "orange"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more reusable (and cleaner IMHO) approach of [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363098/2177402) is to extend `Array`:

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    /// Returns a new array after applying the filter
    var cleaned: [Element] {
        let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ()-/") // note the space
        return filter { $0.rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet) == nil }
    }
}

let teams = ["lime", "teal/gold", "red-2", "orange", "orange(6)", "blue-7"]
print(teams.cleaned) // prints: ["lime", "orange"]
```

---

Or extend `Sequence` if you want to broaden its application:

```
extension Sequence where Element == String {
    /// Returns a new array after applying the filter
    var cleaned: [Element] {
        let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ()-/") // note the space
        return filter { $0.rangeOfCharacter(from: charSet) == nil }
    }
}

let teams = ["lime", "teal/gold", "red-2", "orange", "orange(6)", "blue-7"]
print(teams.cleaned) // prints: ["lime", "orange"]

let set = Set(teams)
print(set.cleaned) // prints: ["orange", "lime"]
```

*(Note: `Set`'s are not ordered)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `filter` operation on your Array. Inside the filter, you just need to call `charsToRemove.contains(where:)` to check if `teamName` contains any of the elements of `charsToRemove` and if it doesn't, keep the team name in the filtered array.

```
let teams = ["lime", "teal/gold", "red-2", "orange", "orange(6)", "blue-7" ]
let charsToRemove = [ "(", ")", "-", " ", "/"]
let filteredTeams = teams.filter({ teamName -> Bool in
    charsToRemove.contains(where: { teamName.contains($0) }) == false
})
```

Comment: `return` keyword is redundant and the ternary condition `? true : false`  is redundant too `charsToRemove.contains { teamName.contains($0)} == false }`

Comment: `filter { !charsToRemove.contains(where: $0.contains) }`

Comment: `== false ? true : false` ... yikes. As Leo said, `filter { !charsToRemove.contains(where: $0.contains) }` is a good option, but some people also prefer `charsToRemove.contains { teamName.contains($0)} == false }`, because the `!` can be hard to see at first glance